# Replacing only digits inside a range of cells in an excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel column with cell values as string mixed with some numbers ar the end. I am not able to do a 'Text to column' as space cannot be a delimiter nor tab.I tried the below code but it works only if the entire cell is a only digits
    I am a beginner in macros and vb

```
Sub ReplaceNoX()
 Dim cell As Object
 Dim val As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim n As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each cell In Selection
 If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
 val = cell.Text
 For i = 1 To Len(val)
 n = Mid(val, i, 1)
 If "0" <= n And n <= "9" Then
 Mid(val, i, 1) = "x"
 End If
 Nextf
 cell.Formula = val
 End If
 Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: You want to replace every digit with an 'x'?

Comment: Can you show some sample data with expected output?

Comment: And is that really `vb.net` code?  Seems you could do that easily with a Regular Expressions

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to replace every digit with an 'x', here is a different approach using regular expressions.

```
Sub Regex1()

Dim oRgx As Object, rCell As Range

Set oRgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With oRgx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d"
    For Each rCell In Selection
        rCell.Value = .Replace(rCell, "x")
    Next rCell
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use your answer to hand you a non-vba alternative? If you would use array formula: `=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(--(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1))),"x",MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))`. It does the same thing and avoids VBA.

Comment: OP wanted a VB solution, and you came up with what I had in mind as well (allthough both answers are good). So maybe it's a nice addition to your answer, to give OP a non-VBA alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change both numbers and mixed text and numbers, then remove the `IsNumeric()` test:

```
Sub ReplaceNoX()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim val As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each cell In Selection
            val = cell.Text
            For i = 1 To Len(val)
                n = Mid(val, i, 1)
                If n Like "[0-9]" Then
                    Mid(val, i, 1) = "x"
                End If
            Next i
            cell.Value = val
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

1. use `Long` rather than `Integer`
2. use `Like` to check individual characters.
3. use `Range` rather than `Object`